# FIleChannel, ByteBuffer why is postion 0 after read?

Tags: java, bytebuffer, filechannel

```
public class CodingDecoding
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try (
                FileChannel out = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("out.txt"),
                        StandardOpenOption.READ,
                        StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                        StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
                FileChannel in = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("in.txt"),
                        StandardOpenOption.READ,
                        StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                        StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

        )
        {

            // write "Hello" to buffer and flip to make buffer ready for writing
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
            buffer.put("Hello".getBytes());
            System.out.println(buffer); // [pos=5 lim=1000 cap=1000]
            buffer.flip();
            System.out.println(buffer); // [pos=0 lim=5 cap=1000]

            // write
            in.write(buffer);
            System.out.println(buffer); //[pos=5 lim=5 cap=1000]

            // flip for reading
            buffer.flip();
            System.out.println(buffer); //[pos=0 lim=5 cap=1000]


            // read
            in.read(buffer);  
            System.out.println(buffer);// [pos=0 lim=5 cap=1000] why pos=0 not pos=5? I didn't read anything?

            // flip for writing
            buffer.flip();
            System.out.println(buffer); //[pos=0 lim=0 cap=1000] so I write nothing to out

            out.write(buffer);
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Can you explain me why pos after read is 0 not 5? I want write "Hello" to in, then read from in and write "Hello" to out. But I dont understand why pos is 0 after read.It's like I haven't read anything.

I tried to write "Hello" to in then read from in, and finally write to out. But I don't understand why is position of buffer = 0 after read.As if I didn't read anything?

Comment: The docs for `read` say the the `position` will be updated by the number of bytes actually read.  I can only assume that no bytes were read for whatever reason. https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer)

Comment: You don't 'flip for reading'. You flip before writing or getting, and you `compact()` after both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FileChannel` object (`in`) is a channel and, itself, has a position. The idea is that after calling `in.write(buffer)`, you can.. call `in.write(buffer)` some more. Your question implies that you think every method call on a `FileChannel` stands alone and goes through the whole process of actually asking the OS to open the file, then do the thing the method call implies (read, or write), and then close it - each method call stands on its own and is independent of all others.

**Not how it works**.

The act of creating the FileChannel opens an OS level resource, and all method calls affect each other. When you call `write`, the FileChannel is now **at position 5** in the new file you have. When you then call read, obviously, you get nothing: That `FileChannel` is at the end of the file so there are no bytes to be read.

### How to fix it

either close the channel and open a new one, or, use `position` to hop around: Add a call to `in.position(0L)` **after** calling `in.write` and **before** calling `in.read`.

Comment: The question is about the `ByteBuffer`'s position, not the file's, and about why it is zero, not 5. You haven't understood the question or spotted the bug in his code.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, the question is about why the position of the `ByteBuffer` is still zero after reading from the `in` channel. And the reason is because no data was read into the buffer. So, the question becomes: Why was no data read into the buffer? Because immediately before reading from `in` the questioner _wrote_ to `in`. They then failed to set the position of `in` back to zero before reading from it. The `in` channel has nothing to read because its position is at the end of the data.

Comment: That's in addition to the problem you point out in [your other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78157321/filechannel-bytebuffer-why-is-postion-0-after-read#comment137789004_78157321).

Comment: @Slaw The question is why position=0 immediately after the read. I’ve answered it in comments. The *subsequent* write is immaterial.

Comment: @user207421 The subsequent write to `out` is not the write I (or this answer) am talking about. It's the _preceding_ write to `in` that's relevant. You're right that the "flip to read" is incorrect, but it's not the direct reason for why the buffer's position is 0. After the call to `flip` the limit is 5 (the exact number of bytes previously written to `in`), meaning there's room in the buffer to read data into. The questioner clearly expected to be able to immediately read the data from `in` that they _just wrote_ to `in`. But they failed to reset the _channel's_ position to 0 before reading.

Comment: @user207421 I've reviewed your comments and you're the one who appears to be misunderstanding a few things. As Slaw points out, the _first_ problem here is attempting to read from a FileChannel that is at the end. That's not the only problem - but the problem you're focusing on (which is indeed a problem) is _secondary_. They're also 'reading it wrong', but the code as written, with the mistakes on calling flip too often and compact not enough - would still read 5 bytes. And applying your fixes without applying the one in this answer would still read zero.